# Getting the id of all the elements in a form with errors

Tags: forms, theming

I am using drupal 6.
All I want is to find the id of each element that has error in form_get_errors.
I am using preprocess to theme the form error section and tried using $vars['form'] with no luck so far.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to write a custom module for this:

1. Use hook_form_alter for the specific form and call form_get_errors.
2. Theme the results of form_get_erros with hook_theme to pass the results back to your theme.

Comment: I already wrote the module but how can i actually know what is the id (css id) for each error in form_get_errors?

Comment: var_dump can show you the contents of the array that is returned with form_get_errors. It won't give you a css id until you output the results in the theme but at least you'll know what elements are available.